# Sampling cliques in an R igraph object

Tags: r, graph-theory, sampling, clique

I would like to randomly sample a clique (not necessarily maximal) from an igraph object.

One approach would be:

```
library(igraph)
G <- erdos.renyi.game(10, .25)  #a small graph
cliques <- cliques(G, min=2)  #list all cliques
sample(cliques,1)  #sample one clique
```

This works fine for small graphs, but a complete enumeration of cliques is impractical for large or dense graphs.

An alternative might involve sampling a node (randomly or proportional to degree), enumerating the cliques in its neighborhood, then sampling from that list. But, I don't think this would randomly sample from all cliques.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!